# React JS - why is this variable behaving like a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created a countdown timer, but I couldn't get the interval to clear with `clearInterval()`. I eventually made the `setInterval` function be inside of a variable, then passed that variable as an argument in `clearInterval()`. What I don't understand is why is the `setInterval` function being called in the first place, because all I'm doing is creating a variable. Do functions inside variable automatically run? Do you not have to call them somehow (how you you even call it if it's inside a variable?). Here is the code that works, but I don't understand why:

```
myFunct () {
  const intervals = setInterval(() => {
    if(this.state.time > 0) {
      this.setState({ time: this.state.time-1 })
    }
    else {
      clearInterval(intervals);
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: "inside of a variable" - what?  The `setInterval()` function returns a value when it's called, and that value is what you have to pass to `clearInterval()`.

Comment: @Pointy

but setInterval() is inside of const intervals =. If I'm just creating a variable (intervals, in this case), why is what I'm setting it equal to being called?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding something fundamental, but I'm not exactly sure what. Your code is calling a method called `setInterval` and assigning the value returned by that method to the variable `intervals`. The method `setInterval` will, in addition to returning a value, set an interval and start running it. What specifically about that process is confusing to you?

Comment: You are setting it up as a variable, which means it is automatically invoked when you run `myFunct`. If you don't want `intervals` to run, turn it into a function by writing it as: `const intervals = () => setInterval`

Comment: @Hamms

Thanks for the responses. I guess it just seems weird that I'm triggering the whole countdown when I'm just setting up a new variable. I guess I'm used to creating variables to just hold strings or integers for use in functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the signature of `setInterval`:

```
window.setInterval(callbackFn, delay, param1, param2, ..)
```

This function returns a number, representing the ID value of the timer that is set. This number can be passed to `window.clearInterval` to clear the timer. So when you call it like this:

```
const myInterval = setInterval(myCallback, 1000);
```

`myInterval` is now a number ID for the timer being run. If `myCallback` calls `clearInterval(myInterval)`, it clears the timer.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval

Comment: Thanks for the respone. I guess I wasn't expecting `setInterval()` to be called in the first place since I was simply setting up a new variable. I figured I would have to induce `myInterval' elsewhere in order for it to be called - which doesn't make sense since it's a variable. I see now that even if I'm just declaring a variable, any function I set it equal to will be called on the spot. Is that correct?

Comment: The declaration of a variable has nothing to do with a function call. In this case, if you call `setInterval(callback, delay)` without a variable on the left hand side, you are just throwing away the return value. By defining a variable you assigned the return value to that variable. If a function that is called returns nothing, a variable on the left hand side will becomes `undefined`. If you want to store a function without calling, it's `const intervalFn = setInterval`. Then you can call `intervalFn` later just like you would `setInterval` (but that's useless).

Comment: I had thought that with a variable on the left hand side, the program wouldn't actually run `setInterval` in the sense that the component wouldn't actually be updated on the page. Clearly it does run. I'm still learning, and I appreciate your helpful responses.

Comment: @Grip try reading up on the difference between expressions and statements. Although in JavaScript semicolons are optional, they are traditionally used to end a statement. A statement does not return or has a value. For instance `const a = 1+ 3;` is a statement, why `1 + 3` is an expression. A function call is an expression that either returns a value or `undefined` or `null`.

Comment: That's definitely an important concept to understand. I'll make sure I understand it wholly so that I don't end up in another situation like this. Again, thanks for taking the time to help me out here. What a great community.